# .NET MVC Service layer constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, service-layer

I'm interested how to implement my constructor in services. I'm a bit new to .NET so don't get me wrong if question is too trivial.

This are my current constructors but I would like to fully understand (since it looks like its working, I took code from somewhere)

```
   // initialize UnitOfWork
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public TownService()
        : this(new UnitOfWork())
    {
    }

    public TownService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

What does `: this` means and which one is called first? Also I saw there is constructor with `: base` but I think thats the one thats calling `superclass` first.

Do I need to call new `UnitOfWork()` ? Isn't `UnitOfWork` supposed to be `factory` (shared) instance? Or it is `factory` and new `UnitOfWork` is not creating new but taking initialized one from memory?

Thanks.

Comment: : this(new UnitOfWork()) means that it calls the constructor with the IUnitOfWork interface parameter. Which one is called first, is determind by the context. Maybe take a read into Dependency Injection first for this matter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, just found out that I have some DI book :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Constructors in C#**

Given your code

```
public TownService()
    : this(new UnitOfWork())
{
  //1
}

public TownService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    //2
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

Invoking `new TownService()` will

- Call the parameterless-constructor
- Instantiate a new `UnitOfWork` and call the overload `TownService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)`, so //2 is executed. This happens because of the `this(...)` call.
- Then execute the parameterless constructor's body, i.e. //1

You need to get an instance of IUnitOfWork from *somewhere*, but calling the parameterless constructor which in turn will instantiate a new `UnitOfWork` probably isn't what you want - it doesn't really buy you much flexibility.

**Using a factory**

If you want to use a factory, you would go something like

```
ITownService s = new TownService(myFactory.Get<IUnitOfWork>());
```

thus avoiding the parameterless constructor.

**Using IoC**

If you want to use an IoC container, you would probably go something like this to configure your container

```
myContainer.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(); //May need to provide database transaction or whatever
myContainer.Register<ITownService, TownService>();
```

You would also need to tell ASP.NET MVC to use the container when creating controllers. You do this by creating a `ControllerFactory` that is aware of your IoC container. Most IoC containers come with such a factory and instructions on how to use it.

Once that is done, you would be able to declare your controllers like

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(ITownService townService) 
    {
      /*...*/
    }
}
```

and have ASP.NET MVC and your IoC container do the rest.

Comment: Actually I have both first and last blocks of code you just wrote... And using ninject I have this:         private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
            kernel.Bind<ITownService>().To<TownService>();
            kernel.Bind<IRestaurantService>().To<RestaurantService>();
            kernel.Bind<IFoodService>().To<FoodService>();
            kernel.Bind<IMenuService>().To<MenuService>();
        }

Comment: Is that enough then or I should add/remove some code?

Comment: Well, does it work? You probably have to tell ASP.NET MVC about Ninject if you haven't done so already. Just google ninject and mvc.

Comment: Looks like it does although I think (as you said) that public TownService()
    : this(new UnitOfWork())
{
  //1
} is code I dont need... Was just interested in those constructors to fully understand them. Will //2 ever be called without that?